# ENV/ARG command not populating variables in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a nanoserver w/ nodejs base image, but I can't seem to get the ARG (or ENV) command to work properly.

My docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver

ENV NODE_VERSION=8.11.4

ADD https://nodejs.org/dist/v${NODE_VERSION}/node-v${NODE_VERSION}-win-x64.zip C:\\build\\node-v${NODE_VERSION}-win-x64.zip


RUN powershell -Command Expand-Archive C:\build\node-v${NODE_VERSION}-win-x64.zip C:\; Rename-Item C:\node-v${NODE_VERSION}-win-x64 node
RUN SETX PATH C:\node

ENTRYPOINT C:\node\node.exe
```

Build command:

```
docker build . -t base-image:latest
```

It downloads the zip file, but when it tries to rename the downloaded file it throws an error:

```
Expand-Archive : The path 'C:\build\node-v-win-x64.zip' either does not exist
or is not a valid file system path.
```

Comment: Did ADD unpack it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer here:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/542

Essentially - within the powershell commands the %VARIABLE_NAME% format has to be used:

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver

ENV NODE_VERSION=8.11.4

ADD https://nodejs.org/dist/v${NODE_VERSION}/node-v${NODE_VERSION}-win-x64.zip C:\\build\\node-v${NODE_VERSION}-win-x64.zip


RUN powershell -Command Expand-Archive C:\build\node-v%NODE_VERSION%-win-x64.zip C:\; Rename-Item C:\node-v%NODE_VERSION%-win-x64 node
RUN SETX PATH C:\node

ENTRYPOINT C:\node\node.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the `ENV` [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement):

> Environment variables are supported by the following list of
>   instructions in the Dockerfile:
>
> ADD COPY ENV EXPOSE FROM LABEL STOPSIGNAL USER VOLUME WORKDIR as well
>   as:
>
> ONBUILD (when combined with one of the supported instructions above)

Therefore it appears variables defined with `ENV` are not supported by the `RUN` directive.

However, you can instead replace the `ENV` directive with the `ARG` directive and `NODE_VERSION` will be availablein subsequent `RUN` directives.

*Example:*

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver

ARG NODE_VERSION=8.11.4

ADD https://nodejs.org/dist/v${NODE_VERSION}/node-v${NODE_VERSION}-win-x64.zip C:\\build\\node-v${NODE_VERSION}-win-x64.zip


RUN powershell -Command Expand-Archive C:\build\node-v${NODE_VERSION}-win-x64.zip C:\; Rename-Item C:\node-v${NODE_VERSION}-win-x64 node
RUN SETX PATH C:\node

ENTRYPOINT C:\node\node.exe
```

Additionally you can override the value of `NODE_VERSION` in your `docker build` command.

`$ docker build -t base-image:latest --build-arg NODE_VERSION=10.0.0 .`

Using the `ARG` directive will not make `NODE_VERSION` available in the environment of a running container. Depending on your use case you may also need to use an additional `ENV` definition.

Comment: I had mistakenly used `ENV` in my first example, I have since edited it. It still doesn't work with the updated version?